# Adding More parameters to REST HTTP GET

Tags: rest, jboss, get, restlet, restful-url

I am trying to access a REST web service using HTTP GET request.

For a example following URI provides Rest web service that return all the available parts for the given category.

```
http://localhost:8080/mycompany/parts/category
```

I want to authenticate/authorize users who are accessing above REST request in each time and I want to pass User authentication details (User Name and Token) with the HTTP Get Request.

Is there a possibility to cater to the above requirement in REST HTTP GET request (using HTTP header or query parameters)?

or

Is it better to use HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET?

Comment: What kind of authentication mechanism do you have in mind? Are you planning to use the standard BASIC/DIGEST mechanisms or a custom auth?

Comment: It depends on the web service if it accepts HttpHeader auth tokens. Some services use OAuth, which often use http header. Check the service documentation, if any... Regarding POST/GET - they are usually used for different actions - GET for READ, and POST for SAVE. You should normally not mix them - each one is used for a specific command.

Comment: @SureshKumar I'm planning use custom Authentication mechanism. I have no Idea on whether it is possible to use standard Auth methods in REST. Im Reading on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting information, you should use "Get".  Here's the code that I use (it is Restlet based) for adding the oauth_token to the request...

```
import org.restlet.data.Reference;
import org.restlet.ext.oauth.OAuthUser;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

Reference commitsRef = new Reference(Consts.RESOURCE_BASE + "commitments/"); 
OAuthUser u = (OAuthUser) request.getClientInfo().getUser();
String token = u.getAccessToken();  
ref.addQueryParameter("oauth_token", token);
ClientResource commitsResource = new ClientResource(getContext(), commitsRef);
Representation commitsRep = commitsResource.get();
```

As mentioned, this is Restlet based, but there is probably something similar in the framework you are using.  (And if you are not using a framework, Restlet can make this easier).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using restlet than good because restlet have rich api for rest framework

but without this if you want to authenticate than
you can do same thing with GET or POST

but send your credential data trough `cookie`

and read same cookie using `@CookieParam` from server side 
in this way you can easily authenticate user.